# Parsing HTML with Indices or Innertext

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

lease note that my question is **specifically targeted at "Simple HTML DOM Library"**!
There are 3k+ lines of code and I have no interest in using a different parser.

A reference can be found here:
"How to find HTML elements" at http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

---

With the following code I'm trying to extract homepage URLs from various `div` elements.

Defining the descendant selectors `div[...] li a` is easy. But to narrow it down to the homepage I tried:

1. the 6th `li` element ... through an index (see below, resulting in error "trying to get property of non-object")
2. that strange `label=Internet:` into the code

Unfortunately I succeeded at neither one :)

**Desired Output**

```
http://www.someurl.com/
http://www.anotherurl.com/
```

**Code that doesn't work**

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=contact-data] li a', 6) as $element_details) {
// variable $html contains the Input listed below 

    // Output $element_details

    }
```

**Input** (stored in variable $html)

```
<div class="contact-data">
    <ul class="plain-list">
    <li>
        Somestreet 18</li>
    <li>
        88888
        Somecity</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Tel:</label>123/123456</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Fax:</label>123/123457</li>

    <li>
        <label>
        E-Mail:</label><a href="http://www.somesite.com/de/Service/ContactParam?mail_pnr=000290080" onclick="">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Internet:</label><a href="http://www.someurl.com/">Homepage</a></li>
    <li>    
        <div style="margin-left: 0px">
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="contact-data">
    <ul class="plain-list">
    <li>
        Anotherstreet 68</li>
    <li>
        88888
        Anothercity</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Tel:</label>123/123447</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Fax:</label>123/123458</li>

    <li>
        <label>
        E-Mail:</label><a href="http://www.anothersite.com/de/Service/ContactParam?mail_pnr=000570030" onclick="">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Internet:</label><a href="http://www.anotherurl.com/">Homepage</a></li>
    <li>    
        <div style="margin-left: 0px">
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need it specifically for simple XML use tags and body text and not title to show that.

Comment: ok, I put that up there in the revised question. my bad

Comment: I have updated an example of what I believe that would help you, I have no experience using that library but it seems that it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and working code

```
<?php
include "simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php";

$str = <<<HTML
<div class="contact-data">
    <ul class="plain-list">
    <li>
        Somestreet 18</li>
    <li>
        88888
        Somecity</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Tel:</label>123/123456</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Fax:</label>123/123457</li>

    <li>
        <label>
        E-Mail:</label><a href="http://www.somesite.com/de/Service/ContactParam?mail_pnr=000290080" onclick="">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Internet:</label><a href="http://www.someurl.com/">Homepage</a></li>
    <li>
        <div style="margin-left: 0px">
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="contact-data">
    <ul class="plain-list">
    <li>
        Anotherstreet 68</li>
    <li>
        88888
        Anothercity</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Tel:</label>123/123447</li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Fax:</label>123/123458</li>

    <li>
        <label>
        E-Mail:</label><a href="http://www.anothersite.com/de/Service/ContactParam?mail_pnr=000570030" onclick="">Contact</a></li>
    <li>
        <label>
        Internet:</label><a href="http://www.anotherurl.com/">Homepage</a></li>
    <li>
        <div style="margin-left: 0px">
        </div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
HTML;

$html= str_get_html($str);

// Find the divs
foreach($html->find('div[class="contact-data"]') as $div)
{
    // Find the listing at the 6th, 
    // however simplehtmldom counts from 0
    $li = $div->find('ul li', 5);
    // Find the link
    $link = $li->find('a', -1);

    // Test if element exist and print if yes
    if(!is_null($link))
        echo $link->href . "\n";
}
```

When using the `foreach` on `$html->find` you cannot use the index or it assumes its a single item.

So first we `foreach` the `div`s, then the single `li` (which was supposed to be at the 6th but it seems it counts from 0 so its on the 5th) from there we find the link and check if it is `null` or not if `null` no `anchor` was found if not we print it.

Output is:

```
http://www.someurl.com/
http://www.anotherurl.com/
```

And if u want you can resume it to:

```
$link = $div->find('ul li', 5)->find('a', -1);
```

Comment: Thanks Prix, had to clarify my question a little:  this is part of a bigger project I have, specifically targeted for "Simple PHP HTML Dom Parser".  Had to partially roll back your revision.  Xpath looks stylish, maybe I'll rewrite everything one day :)

Comment: Ah, too bad, your suggestion sounded so good!  I temp posted the result in my question.  I think we have to close this one for uglyness of code :)

Comment: @somethis also we missed out the `ul` on the search.

Comment: ok, posted.  It runs for hours ... posted the first couple of lines.  The `ul` doesn't seem to make much of a difference, will update my code, though.

Comment: @somethis can you run my code standalone rather than implementing on your app just to see if it does what its supposed to ?

Comment: ok, went standalone.  Can you believe it threw more error messages at me?  If you want to I dropboxed the code:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31129074/rebuild%20of%20scenario.zip

Comment: yes, getting errors with both variants. I have to get offline for today (nine o'clock here).  Thanks for your support, too bad we couldn't solve it, will vote you up as soon as I have necessary 15 points credibility.  Thank you!

Comment: perfect solution!!  Aha, index starts at 0 and splitting up the selectors solved it.  I'll be dancing samba for the rest of the day.  Cleaned up the question and thought about making it more general for others to follow but ... ah, not now :)  Thank you!